# How can I achieve y-axis parallax scrolling using smooth parallax?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to achieve a parallax scrolling effect such as at the top of https://findmymanandvan.co.uk/man-with-a-van/london.  I am using https://github.com/diegoversiani/smooth-parallax but can't seem to make the images move in the x-axis ie. they come in from the sides rather than move up and down on the y-axis?  I'm new to javascript and I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Thanks.

The code I have tried for the images is

```
<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/find-my-man-and-van/image/upload/c_scale,q_50,w_1600/v1653118079/parallax/clouds.webp" alt="clouds" smooth-parallax end-position-y="0.15" id="sky">
<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/find-my-man-and-van/image/upload/c_scale,q_auto:good,w_800/v1652954804/parallax/bground-layer-4-01.webp" alt="mountains" smooth-parallax end-position-y="0.05"
     id="mountainsLayer">
<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/find-my-man-and-van/image/upload/c_scale,q_auto:good,w_1000/v1652954804/parallax/bground-layer-3-01.webp" alt="city" smooth-parallax end-position-y="0.25"
     id="backLayer">
```

With the unchanged javascript from the smooth-parallax library

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
SmoothParallax.init();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Questions should include a [mcve] of a specific issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I have added my test code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 4 parameters, combined with the start-movement and end-movement will make the images you specify move as the page is scrolled:

```
start-position-x - define the horizontal start position of the element in percentage of its the base-size (see option below).
start-position-y - define the vertical start position of the element in percentage of its the base-size (see option below).
end-position-x - define the horizontal end position of the element in percentage of its the base-size (see option below).
end-position-y - define the vertical end position of the element in percentage of its the base-size (see option below).
```